# pyodbc- connection failure to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, windows-7, odbc, pyodbc

I have been trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server. I have an ODBC connection set up and the test is successful. I am not using Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server but it keep getting this error:

> Cannot be used with Windows authentication
>
> InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (18452); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{SQL Server}',
                      Server='servername.abc.xyz.co.com',
                      username = 'user_xyz', 
                      password = 'abcdfgh')
```

I am using Windows 7. Please help me debug this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to solve this by defining the dsn connection as below:

```
dsn="DRIVER={SQL 
SERVER};server=ip_address_here;database=db_name_here;uid=user;pwd=password"
```

This worked and I was able to connect and query the sql server.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it and it works:

```
import pyodbc 

server_name = "server_name"
db_name = "db_name"

server = "Server="+str(server_name)
db = "Database="+str(db_name)
key = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"+server+";"+db+";"+"Trusted_Connection=yes;"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(key)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that example before but didnt work for me. I will post what worked for me.