# Connecting Python to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I work for a nonprofit and I am trying to establish a connection from python scripts to our sql server (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18) as a proof of thought and I am running into an error found below. I cannot find a solution and I have searched across StackOverflow and have tried different arrangements of codes to no success. Underneath the error is my code to connect to sql using pyodbc. I have been successful establishing a remote connection to sql on R (RODBC package) but trying to move to python. Is this a security issue on the SQL server side or am I missing a syntax? For security purposes, I filled in the username and password with fill-ins. Any help would be great!

> ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "foodbankcenc.org" requested by the login.  The login failed. (40532) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "foodbankcenc.org" requested by the login.  The login failed. (40532)')

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
                      Server= 'fbnc.database.windows.net',
                      Database= 'FBData',
                      user ='user',
                      password= 'password')


cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')

for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I think you are missing a port number. Do you know what port the db is running on?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162041/cant-connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-visual-studio

Comment: @Kyriazis I added the port number and still running into the same issues. Could it be on the sql side? However, I am able to connect sql to r through an odbc connection i established for it

Comment: @gajendragarg Following that article you shared! It just gave me that new error I pasted above

Comment: @gajendragarg That was the suggestion I tried when I received the error!

Comment: Ok, then here's the new SO link that solves new error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053602/pyodbc-connection-failure-to-sql-server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242276/discussion-between-gajendragarg-and-beginnerprogrammer).